# How does Boxed closure calls work just like closure calls?

Tags: rust

Why does calling boxed closures work just like calling closures? Is it because of Deref implementation of Box ? Would it work on all smart pointers? As I tried some examples to better understand it, I get the following error.

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = String::new();
    let y = || {
        let t = &mut x;
    };
    let mut ww = Box::new(y);
    (&mut ww)();
}
```

This throws an error

```
error[E0525]: expected a closure that implements the `Fn` trait, but this closure only implements `FnMut`
  --> src/main.rs:22:13
   |
22 |     let y = || {
   |             ^^ this closure implements `FnMut`, not `Fn`
23 |         let t = &mut x;
   |                      - closure is `FnMut` because it mutates the variable `x` here
...
26 |     (&mut ww)();
   |     ----------- the requirement to implement `Fn` derives from here
```

Any documentation on how boxed closures work would be helpful as well.

Comment: Yes, it is because of the `Deref` and `DerefMut` implementations. However, for reasons that aren't immediately obvious to me, the compiler does not seem to be doing mutable dereferencing, but only immutable dereferencing (hence the `Fn` vs `FnMut` error) in this case. If you force mutable dereferencing by using the deref operator as `(&mut *ww)()`, the code compiles.

Answer (score 0):

Box implements all FnX traits since Rust 1.35 ([more info here](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2019/05/23/Rust-1.35.0.html), [source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/boxed.rs.html#1696)), so it should be callable.

Looks like in this particular case the compiler is not smart enough to deref and cast your type which is `&mut Box<Closure>` into expected `Box<impl FnMut() -> ()>` to perform the call directly.

This works though:

```
(ww as Box::<dyn FnMut() -> ()>)();
```

And this works too:

```
ww.as_mut()()
```

Comment: This is not entirely true. ``impl<Args, F, A> FnOnce<Args> for Box<F, A> `` implementation do exist. And if I convert above into trait object ``Box<dyn FnOnce()>`` the above example would work as it is without any deref.

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing out, I've updated the answer.