# Expected a closure that implements the `FnMut` trait, but this closure only implements `FnOnce`

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = String::new();
    let y = || {
        let t = x;
    };
    let mut ww = Box::new(y);
    ww();
}
```

I expect it to run without any error as this implementation exist

```
impl<Args, F, A> FnOnce<Args> for Box<F, A>
```

But I am getting some weird errors which I am unable to understand why?

```
error[E0525]: expected a closure that implements the `FnMut` trait, but this closure only implements `FnOnce`
  --> src/main.rs:22:13
   |
22 |     let y = || {
   |             ^^ this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `FnMut`
23 |         let t = x;
   |                 - closure is `FnOnce` because it moves the variable `x` out of its environment
...
26 |     ww();
   |     ---- the requirement to implement `FnMut` derives from here

error[E0525]: expected a closure that implements the `Fn` trait, but this closure only implements `FnOnce`
  --> src/main.rs:22:13
   |
22 |     let y = || {
   |             ^^ this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `Fn`
23 |         let t = x;
   |                 - closure is `FnOnce` because it moves the variable `x` out of its environment
...
26 |     ww();
   |     ---- the requirement to implement `Fn` derives from here
```

Comment: I am not running it more than once. I just want it to be run once just like ``FnOnce`` closure. This is just an example i am trying to better understand Fn* traits.

Comment: Hum... You're right. I don't know why it's not automatically solved. A workaround is to dereference yourself: `(*ww)();`

Comment: Hm. It compiles if you give `ww` an explicit `FnOnce` type: `let mut ww: Box<dyn FnOnce()> = Box::new(y)`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman That changes the semantics, though, because now you're invoking the closure through a trait object's vtable. I'm not saying that OP didn't want that - trait object dynamic dispatch is typically the _reason_ why one boxes a closure - just pointing out that it's not the same thing. `(*ww)()` is the way to call the closure as created in the question, but it's a good question why `ww()` doesn't just work, as it does when the closure is not boxed.

Comment: ``impl<Args, F, A> FnOnce<Args> for Box<F, A> `` this implementation exist which dereference the box to own closure and ``call_once`` it . Am I wrong in assuming it?

Comment: Related: [users.rust-lang.org discussion](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/expected-a-closure-that-implements-the-fnmut-trait-but-this-closure-only-implements-fnonce/68248)

Comment: So should I report this as a bug?

Answer (score -1):

[Community Work In Progress]

A solution is to dereference yourself:

```rust
(*ww)();
```

Now why the compiler do that:

`Box` impl [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html#impl-FnOnce%3CArgs%3E) but by default it's seem to call `FnMut` See [How does Boxed closure calls work just like closure calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70215236/7076153)

When you do:

```rust
let mut ww = Box::new(y);
ww();
```

It's suppose to call `deref` and [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#impl-Deref) is implemented for box but return a `&T` by borowing the box. `FnOnce` require a move of the box. Why by doing (*ww) this work ? `ww.deref()` and `ww.deref_mut()` doesn't work. It's strange. `*` could call a magic trait instead ? https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.CoerceUnsized.html ? https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DispatchFromDyn.html ?

Comment: @user4815162342 You're right